# Namespace error when adding viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, namespaces

I come to you with a very strange problem.
At the first look it's an easy thing but trust me it's make me crazy !

I just want to specify wich file I want to associate to xaml page in DataContext, I already did it on other xaml page so I don't understand why !

```
<UserControl x:Class="FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home.HomeMusique"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home"
         xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:FinalMediaPlayer.Tools"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:HomeViewModelMusique></viewmodel:HomeViewModelMusique>(error here)
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The name "HomeViewModelMusique" doesn't exist "clr-namespace:FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home".

```
namespace FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home
{
public class HomeViewModelMusique : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
```

As you can see I put the path in viewmodel but apparently the file don't exist in the namespace ...
Thanks by advance guys, Im gonna suicide very soon...

Comment: Have you tried *Rebuild* your solution after adding `xmlns:viewmodel` ?

Comment: Is the viewmodel in the same assembly? If it's in a different assembly, you'll need to specify the assembly in the xmlns:* attribute, like so: `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"`. Incidentally, you're not "associating" any files with anything. You're assigning an instance of a viewmodel class to the UserControl's DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

Are all the namespaces in the same assembly? If they are not you will need to specify the assembly in the namespace declaration.

E.g:

```
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home;assembly=AssemblyName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the namespace is actually correct, then clean\rebuild your solution. Please consider also to use a tool like Resharper that will fix these problems automatically

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast answers guys !
I already try that :

```
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home;assembly=FinalMediaPlayer"
```

It doesn't work, "FinalMediaPlayer" is the name of my project, is there what is expected in the field assembly ?
I Get this on my AssemblyInfos.cs :

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("FinalMediaPlayer")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("FinalMediaPlayer")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

However Im gonna try to use Resharper but this is not a real solution :/.
If I find the solution I will post it.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did try running? Did you try rebuilding as Martino said? WPF designer sometimes needs a rebuild to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry guys I didn't answer that question, of course I did it.
Tryed tot clean/regenerate/generate. Whith no success.
Really I can't believe it, I have spend all my afternoon on this little stupid problem, maybe it's a bug coming from visual studio.
Im gonna try on my other computer later after work.
Again, Thanks to search with me.

```
namespace FinalMediaPlayer.Onglet.Musique.Home
{
public class HomeViewModelMusique : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
```

Comment: Please update your question with the class definition of  HomeViewModelMusique and its namespace definition. As the problem may be there.